# Assign Struct A to B, where elements of A are subset of B

Tags: c, struct

As I understand assigning arrays is a Memory copy operation, will this work?

```
struct x{
    int i;
    int j;
} A[5];

struct y{
    int i;
    int j;
    struct y * next;
} B[5];
```

Then can I do:

```
B[0] = A[0];
```

and expect i and j copied over for index [0]?

EDIT: What I really want to know is how to make this work in C.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?  Or are you asking if we know another way to make it work?

Comment: Yes, thats more appropriate question. How to make this work. I will edit the original question with what I am doing

Comment: Gotcha.  memcpy will do that for you.  [Here is a reference to memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcpy/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that line of code will not compile.

See http://codepad.org/6g3c9Ctz

You can use `memcpy` to make it work.  See http://codepad.org/1I9Z3npC

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct x{
    int i;
    int j;
} A[5];

struct y{
    int i;
    int j;
    struct y * next;
} B[5];

int main() {
    A[0].i = 5;
    A[0].j = 7;
    memcpy(&B[0], &A[0], sizeof A[0]);
    printf("%d %d\n", B[0].i, B[0].j);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the memory alignment nessescarily the same for `x.j` and `y.j` ? I know it will probably be in practice, but I only think it's guaranteed for `i`. The simpler solution is to embed `struct x` in `struct y`.

Comment: Addendum: The fact that this works was formalized in C99.  Prior to C99 there were no guarantees, but it worked in all of the implementations anyway.

Comment: @gnud: As of C99, it is explicitly guaranteed to work even without embedding `struct x` into `struct y`.  As the standards committee noted, it always worked *anyway*, and they just wanted to codify existing practices.

Comment: The C99 standard is [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf).  The details of why memcpy works here are in 6.7.2.1.  Basically it says the fields are layed out in the order declared, and that padding (I think), if it exists, should be consistently applied.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to embed `struct x` in `struct y`, like so:

```
struct x{
    int i;
    int j;
} A[5];

struct y{
    struct x x;
    struct y * next;
} B[5];
```

That way, it's easy to assign, and the memory layout of the first `sizeof(struct x)` bytes of both structs are guaranteed to be the same, even in C89.

You can now do

```
B[0].x = A[0];
```

Since the `struct x` is guaranteed to appear at the first byte of `struct y` in memory, you can still do

```
memcpy(&B[0], &A[0], sizeof A[0]);
```

You can play with this layout at http://codepad.org/2rCJA0cx

Comment: +1: Not to mention that if you modify the structure x later on, you will be sure not to break anything.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot, because struct x and struct y are not compatible types.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a cast:

```
(struct x)(B[0]) = A[0];
```